# SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1118 Row size too large

Tags: magento2.3

HI am getting this error while more columns to sales_order and quote table

**SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1118 Row size too large. The maximum row size for the used table type, not counting BLOBs, is 8126. This includes storage overhead, check the manual. You have to change some columns to TEXT or BLOBs**

even though i have text fields still am getting the issue below is my code

```
class InstallSchema implements InstallSchemaInterface
{
    public function install(
        SchemaSetupInterface $setup, 
        ModuleContextInterface $context
    ){
        $setup->startSetup();

        $quote = $setup->getTable('quote');
        $salesOrder = $setup->getTable('sales_order');
        
        
        $setup->getConnection()->addColumn(
            $quote,
            'shippingaccntno',
            [
                'type' => \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
                // 'nullable' => true,
                'comment' =>'Shipping Carrear Account No'
            ]
        );

        $setup->getConnection()->addColumn(
            $quote,
            'dropdown',
            [
                'type' => \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
                // 'nullable' => true,
                'comment' =>'Drop Down'
            ]
        );

        $setup->getConnection()->addColumn(
            $quote,
            'deliverytelephoneno',
            [
                'type' => \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
                // 'nullable' => true,
                'comment' =>'Delivery Tele Phone Number'
            ]
        );
        

        $setup->getConnection()->addColumn(
            $salesOrder,
            'shippingaccntno',
            [
                'type' => \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
                // 'nullable' => true,
                'comment' =>'Shipping Carrear Account No'
            ]
        );

        $setup->getConnection()->addColumn(
            $salesOrder,
            'dropdown',
            [
                'type' => \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
                // 'nullable' => true,
                'comment' =>'Drop Down'
            ]
        );

        $setup->getConnection()->addColumn(
            $salesOrder,
            'deliverytelephoneno',
            [
                'type' => \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
                // 'nullable' => true,
                'comment' =>'Delivery Tele Phone Number'
            ]
        );
        
        $setup->endSetup();
    }
}
```

am not very much familiar with linux and starting to get used to this so please explain me about this issue

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure this is because of this.

Look like this is a mysql issue.

Kindly, check this link [MySQL: Error Code: 1118 Row size too large (> 8126). Changing some columns to TEXT or BLOB](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25373052/6803218)

If this helps then hit like.

Thank you
Hiren Patel

Comment: the solution over there is way too old and does not work anymore